# Unable to click on sign in to Google button after installing Google api in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, google-plugin-eclipse

I have install the google plugin in for Eclipse from the Android Software Development Tool.
There is a sign in to google button at the bottom right hand corner of the screen.
The button appear grey in color and when i click on nothing happen.
Need some help in troubleshooting this problem

Comment: turns out that the solutions to this problem is due to download the wrong plugin.
I was using eclipse 4.2 while i dl the google plugin for 4.3 Kelvar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you used GOOGLE PLAY SERVICE v13 then you should expect this because the library is buggy and will be fixed in next release don't worry you can't do anything about it.